# Transformation of random Variable that appends a constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a function $g(x)=(x_1, \dots, x_n, 1)$ (=just appends one to the vector). Now, let's say $X$ is a random variable, then $g(X)$ must also be a random variable. But what have I done here? What is it's distribution of $g(X)$?

Something like $D_X \times Dirac$, where $Dirac$ is the Dirac-Distribution and $D_X$ is the Distribution of $X$?

My probability-theory background is a bit weak, so I think I just want to make sure that the math checks out (in a rigorous sense, I need this in a proof!).

EDIT: this is not homework, just to be sure

Example: $X \sim\ N(0,1)$, what's the distribution of $g(X)$?

Comment: Your notation is a little confusing.  When you say $D_X$ is the distribution of $X$, what do you mean?  How does the Dirac distribution (?) fit in?

Comment: thanks, I added an example. is it clearer now? I mean $X \sim\ D_X$ when I say $X$ is $D_X$ distributed. Well, it must be Dirac distributed, doesn't it? It's a coupling of $X$ with a constant, so i don't see how it can be modeled in another way.

Comment: Is $X$ an n dimensional random variable, where each component is standard normally distributed and $g(X)$ is an n+1 dimensional vector with the first n components $X$ and the extra component 1?  If so, you gt it right.